# How to split sentence in a list based on two words?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of string like this `lst = ['John Kim and Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai with Kaster Baldwin']`, and I would like to split the words in list if they have and or with as separators such that the final outcome is `['John Kim', 'Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai', 'Kaster Baldwin']`. How do I achieve this? My try was:

```
to_ret = []
for words in lst:
 splitted = words.split(' and')
 to_ret.extend(splitted)
new_ret = []
for words in to_ret:
 splitted = words.split(' with')
 new_ret.extend(splitted)
```

but this looks very repetitive. Any suggestions for cleaner code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to handle the multiple delimiters, and chain to put all of the sublists into one.

```
import re
from itertools import chain
lst = ['John Kim and Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai with Kaster Baldwin']

output = [w.strip() for w in chain.from_iterable([re.split(r'and|with',x) for x in lst])]
print(output)
```

Output

```
['John Kim', 'Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai', 'Kaster Baldwin']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#my interpretation would be
lst = ['John Kim and Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai with Kaster Baldwin']


toSplitWith= ["and" , "with"]

ans=[]
for word in lst:
    for sprt in toSplitWith:
        if sprt in word:
            ans.extend(word.split(sprt))

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this if you like: -

```
lst = ['John Kim and Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai with Kaster Baldwin']
to_ret = []
for i,word in enumerate(lst):
 splittedand = word.split(' and')
 splittedwith = word.split(' with')
 to_ret.extend(splittedand)
 to_ret.extend(splittedwith)
 to_ret.remove(word)
print(to_ret)
```

out:

```
['John Kim', ' Kerry Lin', 'John Cena', 'Kim Rai', ' Kaster Baldwin']
```